# Cordova App from scratch, decisions about ngCordova,Ionic and Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm planning on making an multiplatform Cordova App (Android,iOS,Windows) and I found different ways to aproach this.

My plan is to develop an application with 4 or 5 functionalities related with the consumption of services (list,add and edit items) and allow offline use of the app.

The most important aspect is that it must be robust and stable above all else.

My solutions were:

- Make a "pure" Cordova (Javascript, HTLM and CSS);
- Use ngCordova (AngularJS, support for Cordova Plugins);
- Use Ionic (AngularJS, mostly UI);
- Use Typescript;
- Use Typescript, ngCordova and Ionic (or a combination of the three together).

I know DefinitelyTyped supports [Ionic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ionic) and [ngCordova](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ng-cordova) (source on links)for the most part and that I can create a blank Cordova App in Typescript so that shouldn't be a problem.

The use of Typescript seems a foregone conclusion but I'm not totally sure about the use of ngCordova and Ionic, what is the standard for nowadays?

EDIT:
Decided to go with Typescript, Angular 2.0 and Ionic 2 but later gave up and developed in Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many standards, and which ones you use are really up to you depending on your needs and how much time you have to learn new technologies. I'll offer an opinion though: you should definitely use some type of an application framework vs. reinventing the wheel, and Ionic is a nice one that happens to be built on AngularJS. ngCordova allows you to access Cordova plugins as AngularJS components and takes about 5 minutes to learn, so if you go with Ionic I would use ngCordova as well. As an alternative, jQuery Mobile is a nice UI framework that, when paired with jQuery, can form a solid foundation for your app.

Comment: I am very inclined to use both ngCordova and Ionic and it's easy to see the advantages it brings to a project! 

I will wait for more answers especially regarding the use of typescript combined with this 2 frameworks.

Thanks for your opinion!

Comment: Im sure ngCordova ships with the Ionic JS libraries because Ionic developed it. It basically wraps most plugins in promises but with some plugins this can cause issues (at least i've experienced it so I had to go back to the native way of using the plugins). Ionic 2 / Angular 2 use TypeScript anyway and they both appear to be in beta stages of release :) above all I recommend Ionic as well it has such a big helping community and their developer team is great!

Comment: Guys, do you have any idea on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116796/grunt-file-not-loading-ngcordova-and-jquery/37118392?noredirect=1#comment61779181_37118392

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend Ionic because Ionic is build ontop of Cordova and makes UI Implementation easy (with predefined components). 
You can also try React Native
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

Comment: Have you tried using Ionic and Typescript? Even in the official blog they have tutorials about that so I imagine it won't be a problem.

And thank you very much for your answer.